# Webhook warnings before purging an envelope

Tags: docusignapi

I am working on integrating DocuSign into our product, and I have noticed that demo envelopes are being purged every 30 days [as stated in the documentation](https://support.docusign.com/articles/How-long-does-DocuSign-store-my-documents). We have set up our product to use a webhook to keep up-to-date with DocuSign's envelope data. However, there doesn't appear to be any warning via webhook before the envelope is purged, it is just suddenly inaccessible. Is there any way to allow notification via webhook before an envelope is purged? Is there any way to find out that an envelope was purged other than hitting an endpoint and then receiving an `ENVELOPE_DOES_NOT_EXIST` error?

Additionally, does the purging of demo envelopes behave in the same way that setting rules for [Document Rentention](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-admin-guide-document-retention) purges envelopes?

Answer (score 1):

Demo (also known as developer sandbox) is a testing and demonstration environment and cannot be used for real work.
The documents signed in demo are not legally binding. You get to play with all the functionality for free without any limits.
Except that DocuSign has to clean it so that storage size don't get out of hand.
So, there are no warnings or notifications in demo.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting that the Demo removal of envelopes isn't the same as Document Retention in Production.

In Production, envelopes targeted for purge will send a warning to signers that have a DocuSign account and they are placed in a two-week queue. After the two weeks, the documents are removed, but there is still a stub record that contains the certificate of completion.

In Demo envelopes are immediately removed without warning once they've hit the 30 day mark, and once they're gone there's zero record that the envelope ever existed.

But to answer the immediate question: No, Connect cannot be used to notify about a document that is pending removal in Demo.